# Are using Apple Maps in iOS applications is free of charge?

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

I just need a straight forward answer. Is using AppleMaps in iOS free of charge? Can't find any straight forward answer on the net. I know that Google limits free map loads to 25k per day over 90 days. No limits on Apple Maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the fee is effectively included in your $99 Developer Program fee and the 30% cut of sales.

Comment: Now that was a traightforward answer